# Why this program crashes after the first loop?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Stroustrup's book to learn C++.

There is an exercise:

> Make a vector holding the ten string values "zero" , "one" , . . . "nine" . Use that in a program that converts a digit to its corresponding spelled-out value; e.g., the input 7 gives the output seven . Have the same program, using the same input loop, convert spelled-out numbers into their digit form; e.g., the input seven gives the output 7 .

I've done it, and here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> numbers = {"zero", "one", "two",   "three", "four",
                              "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    cout << "Insert a number: \n";

    int number = 0;

    while (cin >> number) {
        cout << "\n" << number << "\t" << numbers[number] << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nInsert a number spelled: \n";

    string num;
    while (cin >> num) {
        for (int i = 0; i = numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (num == numbers[i]) {
                cout << "\n" << num << "\t" << numbers[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, the first part goes (if I enter 7 it says "seven", but when I insert | to close the first `while` cycle, the program crashes.

Why is that error occurring?

P.S.: Sorry if I've made some grammar errors but I'm not English.

Comment: How does the program "crash"? What does the debugger say?

Comment: At first glance, your `for` loop is wrong; it should be `for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size();i++)`. But if there is a crash, I think it is caused by the '|' symbol. (Ironic, if a pipe symbol is clogging the plumbing!)

Comment: The for loop was wrong, now it doesn't crash but after the program prints "Insert a number spelled" the program exit, while loop isn't done.

Comment: Your first loop terminated because `std::cin` is in bad state, it does not enter the second loop for the same exact reason. You need to reset `std::cin` state before second loop.

Comment: ...Which you can do with `cin.clear();`. (And I now see the cause of the crash-- the `i = numbers.size()` was an *assignment*, not a test, so it set `i` to the size of the array and then the loop tried to read past the end of the array.)

Comment: Thanks for all, now it runs well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not considering the silly mistake (`=` instead of `==`) in the `for` loop , currently your result is due to the fact that your are exiting the first `while` loop by typing wrong input format (`|` instead of the expected `int`) which causes `cin` to be in bad state that persists to the next `while` loop forbidding further input reading.

If you want your program to continue after the first `while` loop you should define a termination condition, i.e. an input symbol for which your `while` loop `break`s. Additionally, you should include checking (and clearing) of `cin` [stream states](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/).

Answer (score 0):

I found solve to this issue, however there are 2 string vectors

```
// libraries
using namespace std;
int main()
{

vector<string> values1{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
vector<string> values2{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six","seven", "eight", "nine" };

char loop = 'y';

cout << "This program spells out digits or converts them.\n";

while (loop == 'y')
{ 
cout << "Please enter a digit between 0 - 9 to spell out or write a digit to convert to a number: \n";
string digit;
cin >> digit;

for (int i = 0; i < values1.size(); ++i)
{
if (digit == values1[i])
{
cout << values2[i] << endl;
}
else if (values2[i] == digit)
{
cout << values1[i] << endl;
}
}

cout << "Would you like to continue? y / n \n";
cin >> loop;
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above one is wrong in my opinion, finally I found better solution

```
using namespace std;

vector <string> numbers;
void init_numbers()
{
numbers.push_back("zero");
numbers.push_back("one");
numbers.push_back("two");
numbers.push_back("three");
numbers.push_back("four");
numbers.push_back("five");
numbers.push_back("six");
numbers.push_back("seven");
numbers.push_back("eight");
numbers.push_back("nine");  
}

int get_number()
{
const int not_symbol = numbers.size();
int val = not_symbol;

if (cin >> val)
{
    return val;
}

cin.clear();
string s;
cin >> s;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    if (numbers[i] == s)
    {
        val = i;
    }


if (val == not_symbol)
{
    ("there is no number like ", s);
}

return val;
}

int main()

{
init_numbers();

    cout << "type your digit \n";
    int val = get_number();

    cout << "your number is " << val << "\n";


 }
```